# Dropdown list does not populate with API data in Angular

Tags: object, data-binding, foreign-keys, angular8

I know that similar questions have been asked, but I've found none with a good answer. **I want to create a select list in an Angular form, where the value for each option is an object**. I have no backend error and i have no frontend error.
Backend: Spring boot
,Frontend : Angular 9

here is what i've got in option value = [object,object]:

[here is what i've got in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgg8u.png)

here is the **Model**

```
export class Societe {

id: number;
nomSociete: String;
registreCommercial: String;
dateConstruction: Date;
formeJuridique: String;
telephone: Number;
fax: Number;
siteWeb: String;
secteur : Secteur;
}
```

here is the **TypeScript component** :

```html
export class CreateSocieteComponent implements OnInit {
  form: any = {secteur: Secteur};
 

  id: number;
  societe: Societe;
  secteur: Secteur;
  
  constructor(private tokenStorageService: TokenStorageService,private societeService: SocieteService,
 private secteurService: SecteurService , private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }


    getSelectedSecteur(): void{  
     this.secteurService.listerSecteur()
        .subscribe(secteur => this.secteur= secteur);
    }
    //methods to get dropdown values
    dropDownProjectName: string = '';
    selectedHandlerProjectName(event : any)
    {
      if(event.target.value != 'default') { this.dropDownProjectName = event.target.value;}
      else {this.dropDownProjectName = null;}
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getSelectedSecteur();

  }
```

here is **HTML code** :

```html
  <div class="dropdown  ml-auto">
              <select class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" >
                <option value="default">Select Secteur</option>
                <option *ngFor="let Secteur of secteur" [value]="secteur">{{secteur}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

i didn't understand why i'm getting select option [object,object] instead of list of secteur .
ANY HELP !!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try...

```html
<option *ngFor="let sec of secteur; let i = index" [value]="secteur[i].id">
    {{secteur[i].name}}
</option>
```